# NodeJS–Add Array of String in PostgreSQL Query

Tags: node.js, arrays, postgresql, sql-insert, node-postgres

I am trying to write a postgres query (executed in nodejs using a pool created using the node-postgres package) that will insert a new row in a table. One of the columns in this table is of type `text[]`. My code is as follows:

```
pool.query('INSERT INTO paragraphs (lines) VALUES (ARRAY[$1]::TEXT[]) RETURNING id', [my_array], (err, results) => {
            if (err) {
              reject(err)
              return;
            }
            
            resolve(results.rows[0].id)
})
```

`paragraphs` is the name of my table and `lines` is the name of the column of type `text[]`. `my_array` is a list of strings. My problem is that what is inserted is not an array of strings, but rather a single string formatted like an array. e.x.:

`{"[\"First line\", \"Second line\", \"Third Line\"]"}`

I want it to be:

`{"First line", "Second line", "Third Line"}`

I have also tried taking out the `ARRAY` and `TEXT` parts (so the sql looks like `INSERT INTO paragraphs (lines) VALUES ($1) RETURNING id` in the above query), but then I receive the errors:

```
malformed array literal: "["New First line", "Second line", "Third Line"]"
DETAIL:  "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.
```

What is the correct way to insert lists of strings into PostgreSQL tables in nodejs through a query executed by a pool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to: https://node-postgres.com/features/queries#parameterized-query

> Parameters passed as the second argument to query() will be converted to raw data types using the following rules:
> ...
>
> Array
>
> Converted to a string that describes a Postgres array. Each array item is recursively converted using the rules described here.

So:

`VALUES ($1)` or `VALUES ($1::TEXT[])`*should* suffice.

Comment: I originally tried that. It turns out that the array I was trying to use as my parameter was actually just a string (I was using body-parser, which for some reason did not parse an array in my post body and left it as a string). Fixing this and using your method worked!